# SQL Server - remove character unless preceding or followed by specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a dataset like this:

```
Data
I have 23, chickens, but no cats
I have 23, chickensx, but no cats
I have 23, chickens,x but no cats
```

I want to remove every comma. Unless it is followed or preceding an x.
So in this case it should become:

```
Data
I have 23 chickens but no cats
I have 23 chickensx, but no cats
I have 23 chickens,x but no cats
```

Any ideas/suggestions on how to do this? I can have multiple comma's in one record and multiple that are followed or preceding an x.

Comment: Use a CLR function that allows you to do a regex replacement. Alternatively, scrub your data in an ETL package. T-SQL is a bad language to do string manipulation in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this kind of work should be in the database but

```
CREATE TABLE T (DATA VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO T(DATA) VALUES 
('I have 23 , chickens, ,x xw, but no cats'),
('I have 23 , chickens, but no ,@, cats'),
('I have 23, chickens, but no cats'),
('I have 23, chickensx, but no cats'),
(', 23!, I have 23, chickens,x, but no cats'),
(' , I have 23, chickens,x but no cats ,x _, _'),
('x,abc , !, x,x,');

DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @DATA = STRING_AGG(DATA, CHAR(9))
FROM T;

WHILE (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^x,%],[^x,%]%', @DATA)) > 0
BEGIN
  SET @DATA = STUFF(@DATA, PATINDEX('%[^x,%],[^x,%]%', @DATA) + 1, 1, '');
END

SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DATA, CHAR(9));
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                   value                   |
+-------------------------------------------+
| I have 23  chickens ,x xw but no cats     |
| I have 23  chickens but no @ cats         |
| I have 23 chickens but no cats            |
| I have 23 chickensx, but no cats          |
|  23! I have 23 chickens,x, but no cats    |
|   I have 23 chickens,x but no cats ,x _ _ |
| x,abc  ! x,x,                             |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9f1e3fe3b2df588e9e335f2d7d78892)**

Or by calling `REPLACE()` function 7 times, with `CHAR()` as

```
SELECT Data,
       REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                               REPLACE(
                                       REPLACE(
                                               REPLACE(
                                                       REPLACE(Data, ',x,', CHAR(1)),
                                                       ',x', CHAR(2)
                                                      ),
                                               'x,', CHAR(9)),
                                       ',', ''),
                               CHAR(1), ',x,'),
                       CHAR(2), ',x'),
               CHAR(9), 'x,') Results
FROM T;
```

Order is from inside to outside (from the inner replace to the top replace)

- Find `',x,'` and replace it with `CHAR(1)`.
- Find `',x'` and relace it with `CHAR(2)`.
- Find `'x,'` and replace it with `CHAR(9)`.
- Find all `','` and replace them with `''`.
- Get back `',x,'`.
- Get back `',x'`.
- Get back `'x,'`.

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ad871c3bfc9cd3efb028e0441330d08)**

Comment: Fails spectacularly on `'I have 23 , chickens, but no cats'`. Yes, that wasn't one of the sample inputs, but this still seems far too brittle.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the comment `STUFF(DATA, PATINDEX('%[0-9] ,%', DATA) +1, 1, '')`

Comment: How's that any improvement? That fails on `'I have 23!, chickens, but no cats'`.  For that matter, it fails on `'action 1, 2, 3'`. The pertinent part of the question is "every comma, unless followed by or preceded by an `x`" -- the presence or absence of numbers, spaces or exclamation marks isn't relevant.

Comment: @JeroenMostert and now?

Comment: Now it's a really good defense of your first sentence (showing why this shouldn't be done in T-SQL). :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT col,
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
   col,',x,','#'),',x','~'),'x,','^'),',',''),'~',',x'),'^','x,'),'#',',x,')
FROM tab
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=384889a0d480bf5728dd93a6c13edb99)**

Comment: Fails for `,x,`

Comment: I won't use thosechars since they could be in the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly pretty, but you could use `REPLACE` to change the character(s) of `'x,'` and `'x,'` to something else, replace all the commas and then change the other characters back:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT String
    FROM (VALUES ('I have 23, chickens, but no cats'),
                 ('I have 23, chickensx, but no cats'),
                 ('I have 23, chickens,x but no cats'))V(String))
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(String,'x,',CHAR(1)),',x',CHAR(2)),',',''),CHAR(2),',x'),CHAR(1),'x,') AS NewString
FROM VTE;
```

An important thing to note is to choose a character that doesn't appear in your string (hence my choice of `CHAR(1)` and `CHAR(2)`, as they aren't "typeable" characters).

Comment: Fails for `chickens,x,` and `,x,`

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

As a one-off task – 'I have a load of data I need to manipulate' – you can do it by a sequence of

- put-in-escape-codes
- remove commas
- unescape escape codes.

You can eyeball your data to make sure you choose escape codes not in the data set. e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE T (DATA VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO T(DATA) VALUES 
('I have 23 , chickens, ,x xw, but no cats'),
('I have 23 , chickens, but no ,@, cats'),
('I have 23, chickens, but no cats'),
('I have 23, chickensx, but no cats'),
(', 23!, I have 23, chickens,x, but no cats'),
(' , I have 23, chickens,x but no cats ,x _, _'),
('x,abc , !, x,x,'),
('I have 23 , chickens, but no cats'),
('I have 23!, chickens, but no cats'),
('chickens,x, and ,x,'),
(',x,x,')


Select
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(
  Replace(Data,
        ',x,', '___[]___'),
        ',x' , '___[___'),
        'x,' , '___]___'),

         ',' , ''),

        '___]___' , 'x,'),
        '___[___' , ',x'),
        '___[]___' , ',x,')

from T
```

But to do this as a reliable repeatable task on data you don't personally inspect, then @Jeroen-Mostert's point about the CLR or ETL is the better way to go.

You could still do it with crude `Replace(Replace(...`. I think. It would have to be

- Choose some escape characters
- Escape each escape characters (e.g. by doubling each `_` `[` `]`
- Escape each sequence that matters `,x,` `x,` `,x`
- Remove commas
- Unescape sequences
- Unescape escape characters.

I think that would be a total of 13 nested `Replaces`.